# SQL Query to Sum Columns for each category

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, report

[image]Please find attached the table I am trying to generate . The output of the query returns data as specified in "Existing Table". I am trying to generate table as in Required Table. Don;t have any success so far.  As you can see in the figure , the column gets added for each State and City.

Any idea how to accomplish this ?. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Appreciate the help .

Comment: I think you forgot to attach the table, sample data, expected result, query, etc.

Comment: Thanks for informing me. I just updated the post with table image.

Comment: Use **ROLLUP** function in SQL Server @bp581

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUM aggregate function with OVER clause as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810(v=sql.105).aspx

As per the above page, the below code should be compatible with your inquiry:

```
SELECT 
    [State], 
    City, 
    Item, 
    Cost, 
    Tax, 
    SUM(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY [State], City) AS CumulativeCost, 
    SUM(Tax) OVER (PARTITION BY [State], City) AS CumulativeTax
FROM -- Replace the below with your table
(
    SELECT 'A' AS [State], 'AC' AS [City], 'Item1' AS [Item], 10 AS [Cost], 1 AS Tax UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS [State], 'AC' AS [City], 'Item2' AS [Item], 30 AS [Cost], 2 AS Tax UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS [State], 'BC' AS [City], 'Item1' AS [Item], 40 AS [Cost], 1 AS Tax UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS [State], 'BC' AS [City], 'Item2' AS [Item], 10 AS [Cost], 1 AS Tax
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

ROLLUP did the trick. Here is the link which I referred.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx